# c# WebBrowser Parsing Javascript Populated Data from a website?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, parsing, browser

My problem is to parse data from a website. The data is created in that website with a    Javascript code:

```
<script type"text/javascript">
Sys.Application.initialize();
</script>
```

with this code the data is filled into a form in that website.

How can I parse this data?

```
WebBrowser webbrowser;
webbrowser.DocumentText;
```

this does not work since the content is created by java and it is not visible in html source.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. 
Let me share with you. I dont know if there is a better approach.

First, I tried to parse data inside table with:

```
String line = null;
HtmlELementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByTagName("tbody");
foreach (HtmlElement row in elems)
{
line +=row.InnerHtml;
}
```

After that I decided to use Regex to parse the exact data from String line 
With MatchCollection I parsed the data I want.

I am not writing that part but if anybody needs more information I can help.

I hope it will be helpful. At least it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the jscript:

```
 var JSource = "my code jscript";
 var result = Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate(JSource, Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine());
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```